# create a timeline view which covers the whole tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have created a table view controller which has a timeline view that ends in the cell which have content.
[image]
As you can see from the picture, vertical line of the tableview ends in the second row of tableview since it is pulling two lists from the array but instead I want to show the vertical line till the bottom and the circle's in the unused table view cell. I created the view programmatically. The custom table view cell looks like

```
private func setUpTimeline(){

        addSubview(bezierLine)

        bezierLine.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 92.5).isActive = true
        bezierLine.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        bezierLine.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.8).isActive = true
        bezierLine.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true


        addSubview(circularCompletion)

        circularCompletion.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bezierLine.leftAnchor, constant: -12.5).isActive = true
        circularCompletion.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        circularCompletion.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
        circularCompletion.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true


        addSubview(timeLabel)
        timeLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        timeLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        timeLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bezierLine.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        timeLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true


        addSubview(surveyNameLabel)
        surveyNameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bezierLine.rightAnchor, constant: 18).isActive = true
        surveyNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.circularCompletion.topAnchor).isActive = true
        surveyNameLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        surveyNameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true

        addSubview(surveyDetailsLabel)
        surveyDetailsLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.surveyNameLabel.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        surveyDetailsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.surveyNameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        surveyDetailsLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.surveyNameLabel.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        surveyDetailsLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15).isActive = true
    }
```

Comment: What about putting that line into the footerView for the rest of it?

Answer (score 0):

This was actually quite easy. I created a class which extends from UIView, and conforms to Tableview datasource, delegate. Created this block,

```
lazy var table: UITableView = {
        var bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let tv = UITableView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: 800))
        tv.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        tv.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
        tv.dataSource = self
        tv.delegate = self
        return tv
    }()
```

Then registered the custom cell,

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(table)

        table.register(EmptyTableViewCells.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }
```

In the main view controller, I created an instance of the class called "surveyFooter" and added it to tableFooterView.

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = surveyFooter
```